# How I can Load another Razor Component into a Razor Component by a Button-click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I just want to load a razor component into another razor component when user click search button then I want to show search razor component (page) into a hidden div when the user click hide button then it will be hidden. like inline popup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

Main Component:

```
@page "/test"


<button @onclick="(() => ShowComponent = true)">Show</button>
<button @onclick="(() => ShowComponent = false)">Hide</button>
@if (ShowComponent)
{
    <ShowHideComponent></ShowHideComponent>
}


@code {
    bool ShowComponent { get; set; } = false;
}
```

`ShowHideComponent.razor`:

```
<div>Show Or Hide This</div>
```